# lazy load image inside hidden container?

Tags: jquery, css, lazy-loading, hidden, pagespeed

I folks.. I hope everything is fine for you!

I got an issue and I need some help...
So, I make a portfolio using the "WM Gridfolio" (WMG) script and I would like to "lazy load" the pictures. I try some "lazy load" script but I didn't get the "effect" wanted !!

So wmg create a grid of thumbs and while I click on one of it, it open a " sub container"
with some text and some "big" images (that I want lazy load)!
But for now everything I tried with some lazy load script, load all the images when reaching the grid, not when the "sub container" is open!

The html part of the WMG is:

```
<div class="wmg-container"><!-- Main grid container -->
  <div class="wmg-item"><!-- First item -->
    <div class="wmg-thumbnail">
      <div class="wmg-thumbnail-content"> 
        <img src="img-1.jpg" alt="image"><!-- Thumbnail on the grid --> 
      </div>
      <div class="wmg-arrow"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="wmg-details"> <span class="wmg-close"></span>
      <div class="wmg-details-content"><!-- Sub container -->
        <div class="container">
            <div class="txt center">
                <h2>A title</h2><hr>
                <p>some text</p>
            </div>
            <div class="container-pics">
                <div class="pics"><img src="image1.jpg" alt=""></div><!-- image to be lazy loaded -->
                <div class="pics"><img src="image2.jpg" alt=""></div><!-- image to be lazy loaded -->
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- second item goes here -->
</div>
```

All the info about this script dispo there: http://www.jqueryscript.net/gallery/jQuery-Plugin-For-Responsive-Portfolio-Gallery-WM-Gridfolio.html

And the Demo (in case): http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-For-Responsive-Portfolio-Gallery-WM-Gridfolio/

It work like that: When clicking on a picture in the grid, the "wmg-container" get a new class "open" and show the "wmg-details-content"!
I thought about perhaps not use a "lazy load" script, but putting the "container-pics" or the img itself with a 'display:none' and change the display when the "Sub container" is open!! ??
But I'm not sure how will react the "loading speed" of the page.. And as the new class "open" is on the main grid container, I thought about that a click on any images in the grid will change the display of all images not just the "sub container" that are currently open!

(There is at least 10 images in the grid with between 1 or 3 images each (in the sub container))

Thanks for any help... If you need more details just ask and I will edit the post!!
Sorry for my english and if I'm not clear !!

Comment: Did you find an anwer for this?